# Crash when trying to make an array overrun

Tags: c, arrays

I read this paragraph in c the complete reference book

> C has no bounds checking on arrays. You could overwrite either end of
>   an array and write into some other variable's data or even into the
>   program's code. As the programmer, it is your job to provide bounds
>   checking where needed. For example, this code will compile without
>   error, but it is incorrect because the for loop will cause the array
>   count to be overrun.
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main(){
>
>
>     int count[10], i;
>     /* this causes count to be overrun */
>     for(i=0; i<15; i++) count[i] = i;
>
>     for(i=0; i<15; i++) printf("%d ",count[i]);
>
>     return 0;
>
> }
> ```

and when I try the code it gives me

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

And then a run time error was displayed on the screen. The error was

> array.exe has stopped working

My question is : What is the type of that error? And does it mean that my IDE checks the bounds of the array?

Comment: So... what's your _question_?

Comment: Try only `11` instead of `15` ;0

Comment: Indexing an array out of bounds has undefined behaviour. ***What you expect to happen?*** In the worst case, that memory location is out of your process virtual space, and the OS kick off you.

Comment: i edited my questions, plz check it again

Comment: @Manu343726 That's what I'd call a best case to be honest. When all works "just fine", but somehow you have these strange bit of data that seem corrupted....then you have a worst case. ;)

Comment: I don't understand all the downvotes -- the question isn't that dumb from a novice programmer's point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C doesn't check array idexing, it does only simple pointer-arithmetic. That is, the standard defines the operation `array[i]` as `array + i`.
Depending on the resulting memory address of that computation, many things can occur:

- **The address points to the location of a local variable of the function**: You modify the local variable. For example:

  ```
  int main()
  {
      int array[10];
      int a = 0;

      array[11] = 22; 

      printf(a%i,a); /* Prints 22 */
  }
  ```

  Remember that the point here is that buffer overrun has undefined behaviour. My example could not work, because the compiler is free to reorder the variables layout during compilation, for memory-aligment and optimising purposes.
- **The address points to the location of a global variable (Thats a very big indexing/jump, but can occur)**: The effect is the same as in the local variable case.
- **The address points to the location where the subroutine stores the return address**: Many architectures stores the return address of a function in a register, but if the architecture stores it in the stackframe of the function... WOW. TRY TO DEBUG THAT!!! :)
- **The address goes out of the memory space of the process:** Modern operative systems always check memory accesses to prevent this, so when this happens the OS kicks you in the ass and throws an exception.

Finally note that things are only applicable in release compilation. In debug mode the compiler adds a lot of code to check this kind of things to throw (Provide) a comprehensible and easy-debuggeable exception.

For example: When allocating dynamic arrays, windows debug-heap first fills the memory space that will be used with a flag which says that memory space is ready to use, but it doesn't contains any data: Thats the hexspeak *0xBADF00D*. After this, `malloc` retrieves the memory location, adding hexspeaks around the array to provide bounds checking.

See [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c9535/Inside-CRT-Debug-Heap-Management.htm) for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The moment the first loop reaches `i=10`, you enter the realm of [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (since you're writing past the end of `count`). From that point on, anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE had nothing to do with it.  The OS killed your program because it tried to access memory that didn't belong to it.

This type of error is usually known as an access violation.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine - and the point of the article you have read...

What you are supposed to do is limit the for loop so that it only runs from 0 to 9.

Or, if you really need 15 items, expand the array to take them...